# Sqlite write concurrency : How to implement buffering?

Tags: php, sqlite

I understand that we can only have one writer at a time on a Sqlite database file. The file is locked and the other writers *processes* are queued up, FIFO.

Is there any technique that allow me to queue the *write queries* instead of the *processes* ? I want to write somewhere (as quick as possible) the transaction itself, and execute them in queue, one by one.

Is the Sqlite's WAL option the solution ? Is there any log mode to insert quickly my queries to a table ? Maybe using a memcached buffer ?

Precision 1 : we are talking about a website with lots of read queries (catalog read), and simples write queries (add to favorite for a user).

Precision 2 : I *can* ignore the content of the buffer file for a little time.

Thanks !

Comment: Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) seems to be a built-in buffer system, but it still queue the processes. Can't see the duration of the lock ?

Comment: Do I get it correctly that you want to buffer modification requests which happen rarely? What's the point if they happen rarely? When you say `insert quickly` what do you mean by that in terms of time? So basically the question is how many statements per second you want to process and how much time it takes to execute the single statement?

Comment: @RomanKonoval : Not "rarely", but less often than reads. 
And basically, my question could be : after how many "concurrent" writes will the lock time will be significant, and how I can reduce this time.

Comment: Sounds like a client-server database would be more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @Shawn Maybe, but I want to know more about Sqlite limit's, because I'am interested in the simplicity of deployment.

Comment: What you want can't be done without writing your own server front end. And at that point it's easier to use a different database that does offer support for multiple simultaneous writers out of the box.

Comment: Yes @Shawn, I understand. 
But what about the WAL mode ? For what I can understand it's a kind of buffer to allow shorter lock when writing (except when commiting a new checkpoint). I try to understand the limits of that : how many "concurent" writes are possible with a short lock time.
Again, the "bundlable" idea of Sqlite is very interesting in my case.

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite the question to be specific about that WAL mode

Comment: Ok I have rewrited a question specificaly for WAL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865379/sqlite-wal-mode-how-much-time-should-i-expect-to-be-locked-in-wal-mode