# Sqlite WAL mode : how much time should I expect to be locked in WAL mode?

Tags: php, sqlite, wal

I plan to use Sqlite with WAL mode (on a web server).

As I understand, the reads are never blocked with this mode, even when write occurs in the same time.

There is still only one write transaction at a time but I guess the lock time is short because the actual write on the db occurs only when the WAL file exceed a certain size.

So :

- How much time should I expect to be locked in WAL mode when the transaction is written on the WAL file ? When the WAL file is commited ?
- Is there any benchmarks out there testing that point ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very quick. I have a web based API (PHP+SQLite) that processes 2 to 5 million (read/write) transactions per month. With PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL there have been no issues. This is only observational data I know, but thought it might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your experience. Do you know how much transaction per second your system can handle (at peak) ?

Comment: We process more than 100k transactions in an hour occasionally, beyond that I've just had no reason to analyze it.